# How to prove that the $\sqrt n$ DOES NOT converge to $L$ using the DEFINITION?

Tags: calculus

Prove using only the definition that: $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n \neq L$

Proof:

There is $ϵ>0$
s.t for every $N$
there is $n>N$ s.t:

$|\sqrt n - L| \ge ϵ$

I multiplied $\sqrt n - L$ by $\frac{\sqrt n + L}{\sqrt n + L}$  and got $|\frac{(\sqrt n - L)(\sqrt n + L)}{\sqrt n + L}| \rightarrow |\frac{n - L^2}{\sqrt n + L}|$

But how do I proceed further?

Comment: You should avoid to use $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n$ because that means that $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sqrt n$ **exists**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $\epsilon=1$. if $n > (L+1)^{2}$ then $\sqrt n -L >\epsilon$ so $|\sqrt n -L |>\epsilon$ too.

Comment: So you claimed that for $ϵ=1$ there is such $N$ that for every $n>N$ $|\sqrt n - L|>ϵ$ is true? But how does it prove that there is such n for every $N$? I am totally confused

Comment: Suppose there is an $N$ such that $|\sqrt n -L|<\epsilon$ whenever $n >N$. Take $n >\max \{N, (L+1)^{2}\}$ to arrive at a  contradiction. @SemyonGlezer